# サイトの初回訪問時だけバナーを表示させたい

Tags: php

考え方で質問させていただきます。
例えばとあるサイトで初めて来た人だけ、バナーを表示させて、それ以降表示させないようなスクリプトを書きたいのです。
dbでinsertして、毎回チェックってのはしたくないです。
cookieにしようかなと思っていますが、何かいいじゃんてきなものがあれば、教えて下さい。

Answer (score 2):

WebStrageを利用する案はいかがでしょうか？
クッキーとは異なり、クライアントごとに永続化されます。

```
  <!doctype html>
  <html lang="ja">
  <head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>WebStrage API</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function init() {
      var hasVisited = localStorage.getItem("visited");
      if( hasVisited != "true"){
         document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = "<h1>ロゴ</h1>";
         localStorage.setItem("visited", "true");
      }
      else [
         document.querySelector("#result").innerHTML = "hoge"
      ]


    }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body onload="init()">
    <div id="result"></div>
  </body>
  </html>
```